# Scala Typeclass with multiple parameters error

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, typeclass

I'm getting a strange error related to types with this multi-parameter typeclass implementation

```
trait Feedtype
trait Atom extends Feedtype
trait Rss2 extends Feedtype
case object Atom extends Atom
case object Rss2 extends Rss2

trait Encoding
trait Xml extends Encoding
trait Json
case object Json extends Json
case object Xml extends Xml

trait Content
case class show[T <: Feedtype,E <: Encoding](str: String, tp: T, en: E) extends Content

trait TypeClass[C,D,E] {
  def show(c: C, d: D, e:E): String
}

trait Service{
  def print[T,C,D](t: T,c:C, d:D)(implicit s: TypeClass[T,C,D]): String
}

object Service extends Service{
  def print[T,C,D](t:T, c:C, d:D)(implicit s: TypeClass[T,C,D]): String =
    s.show(t,c,d)
}

implicit val t1 = new TypeClass[show[Atom,Xml], Atom, Xml] {
  def show(c: show[Atom,Xml], d:Atom, e:Xml) = c.str
}

implicit val t2 = new TypeClass[show[Rss2,Xml], Rss2, Xml] {
  def show(c: show[Rss2,Xml], d:Rss2, e:Xml) = "hi there " + c.str
}

val s1 = show("some show", Atom, new Xml {})

Service.print(s1, s1.tp, s1.en)
```

The error I'm getting is

```
type mismatch;
 found   : A$A10.this.typeclass[A$A10.this.show[A$A10.this.atom,A$A10.this.xml],A$A10.this.atom,A$A10.this.xml]
 required: A$A10.this.typeclass[A$A10.this.show[A$A10.this.atom.type,A$A10.this.xml.type],A$A10.this.atom.type,A$A10.this.xml.type]
service.print(s1, s1.tp, s1.en)(t1);}
                                ^
```

What am I missing here ?

---

**Update**

I figured out that issue is that `atom` and `xml` being `case objects` when they are being used as values to create `s1`. If I use `new atom {}` or `new xml {}` then the execution is happening fine. However, I wonder why are the `case object`s being considered a different type than the types that they represent ?

Comment: What is `atom`? Please post a [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: Missed some parts of code, have fixed it now. Apologies and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out the problem lies here:

```
val s1 = show("some show", Atom, new Xml {})
                //           ^
                // The most specific type of this is Atom.type
```

`Service#print` has its type parameters inferred by the objects passed to it. `s1` is a `show[Atom.type, Xml]`, therefore the compiler is looking for an implicit `TypeClass[show[Atom.type, Xml], Atom.type, Xml]` for `Service#print`. The compiler will not automatically try to upcast an `Atom.type` (the cast object) to an `Atom` for a couple reasons:

1. The compiler does not know a `show[Atom.type, Xml]` is also a `show[Atom, Xml]` (`show` is declared as invariant, and so is `TypeClass`).
2. There is an implicit `TypeClass[show[Atom,Xml], Atom, Xml]` available for the generic `Atom`, but not for the more specific type `Atom.type`.

---

Your example is very complicated, but doesn't need to be to reproduce the issue. Consider this:

```
trait TypeClass[A] {
    def show(a: A): String
}

trait Atom
case object Atom extends Atom

implicit val ar = new TypeClass[Atom] {
    def show(a: Atom): String = "Atom"
}

object Service {
    def print[A](a: A)(implicit tc: TypeClass[A]) = tc.show(a)
}

scala> Service.print(Atom)
<console>:18: error: could not find implicit value for parameter tc: TypeClass[Atom.type]
       Service.print(Atom)
                    ^
```

We get the same compilation error. This is because in the above structure, a `TypeClass[Atom.type]` is not the same as a `TypeClass[Atom]` as far as the compiler is concerned, but it doesn't have to be that way. We can make `TypeClass` *contravariant* over `A`, which means that a `TypeClass[Atom]` may be substituted in place of a `TypeClass[Atom.type]`. It makes sense to do so in this context because `TypeClass` in my example represents a printer-like class. If you know how to print the super-type, you can print a sub-type, but not necessarily the other way around.

```
trait TypeClass[-A] {
    def show(a: A): String
}
```

This will allow the implicit to resolve now. If you want to keep `TypeClass` invariant, we can up-cast the `Atom` ourselves:

```
scala> Service.print(Atom: Atom)
res4: String = Atom
```

---

How to apply this to your example?

The easy way would be to up-cast `Atom`:

```
val s1 = show("some show", Atom: Atom, new Xml {})
```

**Or**, `show` and `TypeClass` cannot be invariant. First, make `show` covariant over `T` so that a `show[Atom.type, B]` is also a `show[Atom, B]`:

```
case class show[+T <: Feedtype, E <: Encoding](str: String, tp: T, en: E) extends Content
```

Then, make `TypeClass` contravariant over `C` and `D`, so that a `TypeClass[show[Atom,Xml], Atom, Xml]` can also be considered a `TypeClass[show[Atom.type, Xml], Atom.type,Xml]`, which will allow the implicit `t1` to be picked up.

```
trait TypeClass[-C, -D, E] {
  def show(c: C, d: D, e:E): String
}

// cutting out putting it all together to save space

scala> val s1 = show("some show", Atom, new Xml {})
s1: show[Atom.type,Xml] = show(some show,Atom,$anon$1@76a4d6c)

scala> Service.print(s1, s1.tp, s1.en)
res1: String = some show
```

Comment: I can't say more how grateful I'm for this detailed answer. Thanks a lot.